# SFMC API authorization error

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Getting below error with my SFMC API call.

I'm passing ClientId, ClientSecret and API endpoint:

`https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken?legacy=1`

```
Unable to determine stack using /platform/v1/endpoints: {
"message": "Authorization token invalid on URL.",
"errorcode": 40003,
"documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm"
```

Comment: Can you add your code so that we know what you are doing in there?

Comment: also what stack are you one?

Comment: What Installed Package type are you using? Is it Legacy or OAuth2? If it's OAuth 2 you're using the wrong endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ensure you are using your tenant-specific Marketing Cloud endpoint, which includes your tenant’s subdomain when making your [request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm).